# Hibernate runs unwanted update statement

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have native query to run :

```
String sqlSelect =
"select r.id_roster as id, " +
                    "count(roster_cat.id_category), " +
            "       sum(case when roster_cat.id_category IN ( :categoryIds)                       then 1 else 0 end) as counter " +
            "from roster r " +
            "inner join roster_sa_categories roster_cat " +
                "on r.id_roster = roster_cat.id_roster " +
            "where r.day = :dayToLookFor " +
                "and r.id_shop = :idShop " +
            "group by r.id_roster " +
            "having count(roster_cat.id_category) = :nrCategories " +
                "and count(roster_cat.id_category) = counter" ;

    Query selectRostersQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlSelect);

    selectRostersQuery.setParameter("categoryIds", Arrays.asList(categoryIds));
    selectRostersQuery.setParameter("dayToLookFor", day.toString());
    selectRostersQuery.setParameter("idShop", shopId);
    selectRostersQuery.setParameter("nrCategories", categoryIds.length);

    List<Integer> rosterIds =  new ArrayList<>();

    List<Object> result = (List<Object>) selectRostersQuery.getResultList();
```

For some reason Hibernate choses to do an update before executing the select and it is really interfering with my data

```
     Hibernate: /* update domain.Roster */ update roster set day=?,     employee_count=?, interval_end=?, interval_start=?, id_shop=? where id_roster=?
     Hibernate: /* update Roster */ update roster set day=?, employee_count=?,  interval_end=?, interval_start=?, id_shop=? where id_roster=?
     Hibernate: /* dynamic native SQL query */ select r.id_roster as id,   count(roster_cat.id_category),sum(case when roster_cat.id_category IN ( ?) then 1 else 0 end) as counter from roster r inner join roster_sa_categories 
roster_cat on r.id_roster = roster_cat.id_roster where r.day = ? and r.id_shop = ? group by r.id_roster having count(roster_cat.id_category) = ? and count(roster_cat.id_category) = counter
```

Any help would be appreciated,Thank you

Comment: I'm inclined to guess that Hiberate has some relevant entity modifications cached, and it needs to flush them to the DB in order to ensure that the query returns correct results.  It's unclear how or why that would be "interfering with [your] data".

Comment: So is there something i can do about this? Because I really need to use the query .

Comment: The point is that Hibernate is almost surely doing what it does because of something else your own code does, and that Hibernate is probably doing the right thing under the circumstances.  I gave you my best guess as to the kind of thing that might be going on, but you really haven't given us much to work with here.  Generally, we want a [mcve].

Comment: Agree with John... you likely selected a `Roster` object previously and modified it somehow. You could run `session.clear()` if you're confident that you don't need any attached entities to stay in your session, but be very careful when messing with that stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is precisely what Hibernate's `FlushMode.AUTO` implies.

Any modifications in the Persistence Context (1LC) at the time a query is executed will be automatically flushed prior to executing the query, guaranteeing that the results returned by the database match that which was cached by in-memory modifications.

If the query is going to return entities that you're seeing the update for, then you should likely re-evaluate your operations, making sure that the query fires prior to the update to avoid the flush operation, which can be quite expensive depending on the volume of entities in your Persistence Context.

If you are **absolutely sure** that the changes you're seeing flushed won't be returned by the query in question, you can always force the query not to cause a flush by setting the flush mode manually:

```
Query query = session.createQuery( ... );
query.setFlushMode( FlushMode.COMMIT );
List results = query.list();
```

But only do this if you're sure that the query wouldn't then be reading uncommitted changes as this can cause lots of problems and lead to long debug sessions to understand why changes are being inadvertantly lost by your application.